# python XML get text inside <p>...</p> tag

Tags: python, xml

I guys, I have an xml structure which looks somewhat like this.

```
<abstract>
  <p id = "p-0001" num = "0000">
     blah blah blah
  </p>
</abstract>
```

I would like to extract the `<p>` tag inside the `<abstract>` tag only.

I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xroot = ET.parse('100/A/US07640598-20100105.XML').getroot()

for row in xroot.iter('p'):
     print row.text
```

This get all the `<p>` tag in my xml which is not a good idea.

Is there anyway i can extract the text inside

My desire output would be extracting "blah blah blah"

Comment: How did you define `xroot`?

Comment: I have edit my question for how i define xroot.

Comment: Please ensure that your questions include all `xmlns=` declarations anywhere above the place in your XML content where the quoted portions are given. If such a declaration exists, then queries searching only in the default namespace will fail to match.

Comment: Thanks, I ll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an *XPath expression* to search for `p` elements specifically inside the `abstract`:

```
for p in xroot.xpath(".//abstract//p"):
    print(p.text.strip())
```

Or, if using `iter()` you may have a nested loop:

```
for abstract in xroot.iter('abstract'):
    for p in abstract.iter('p'):
        print(p.text.strip())
```